# The dashboard (dash) isn't displaying it's graphics

Tags: python, plot, visualization, plotly-dash, dashboard

eventhough the code isn't presenting any explicit error the Dashboard created by the code doesn't display the graphics as it was supposed to.
How can I fix it ?
Sorry for the bad english. Thank you very much!
Here is the code:

```
            import dash
            from dash import dcc
            from dash import html
            from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
            import pandas as pd
            import plotly.graph_objs as go
            import plotly.express as px

            # Load the data using pandas
            data = pd.read_csv('https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DV0101EN-SkillsNetwork/Data%20Files/historical_automobile_sales.csv')

            # Initialize the Dash app
            app = dash.Dash()

            # Set the title of the dashboard
            app.title = "Automobile Sales Statistics Dashboard"

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Create the dropdown menu options
            dropdown_options = [
                                {'label': 'Yearly Statistics', 'value': 'Yearly Statistics'},
                                {'label': 'Recession Period Statistics', 'value': 'Recession Period Statistics'}
                               ]

            # List of years 
            year_list = [i for i in range(1980, 2024, 1)]

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            # Create the layout of the app
            app.layout = html.Div([    
                #TASK 2.1 Add title to the dashboard
                html.H1("Automobile Sales Statistics Dashboard",
                        style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': '#503D36', 'font-size': 24} #May include style for title
                        ),
                #TASK 2.2: Add two dropdown menus
                html.Div([html.Label("Select Statistics:"),
                         dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-statistics',
                                      options=dropdown_options,
                                      value='Yearly Statistics',
                                      placeholder='Select a report type'
                                     )
                        ]),
                html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(id='select-year',
                                      options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
                                      value='2010'
                                      )
                        ),
                #TASK 2.3: Add a division for output display
                html.Div([
                          html.Div(id='output-container-yearly', 
                                   className='chart-grid'
                                  )
                         ])
                             ])

            #TASK 2.4: Creating Callbacks
            # Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
            @app.callback(Output(component_id='select-year', component_property='options'),
                          Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics', component_property='value')
                         )

            def update_input_container(selected_statistics):
                if selected_statistics == 'Yearly Statistics': 
                    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list]
                else:
                    return []

            #Callback for plotting
            # Define the callback function to update the input container based on the selected statistics
            @app.callback( Output(component_id='output-container-yearly', component_property='children'),
                           [Input(component_id='select-year', component_property='value'), 
                           Input(component_id='dropdown-statistics', component_property='value')] )

            def update_output_container(report_type, input_year):

                if report_type == 'Recession Period Statistics':
                    
                    # Filter the data for recession periods
                    recession_data = data[data['Recession'] == 1]
                    
            #TASK 2.5: Create and display graphs for Recession Report Statistics

            #Plot 1 Automobile sales fluctuate over Recession Period (year wise) 
                    #use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
                    yearly_rec = recession_data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
                    R_chart1 = dcc.Graph(figure = px.line(yearly_rec,
                                                          x='Year',
                                                          y='Automobile_Sales',
                                                          title="Average Automobile Sales fluctuation over Recession Period"
                                                          )
                                        )

            #Plot 2 Calculate the average number of vehicles sold by vehicle type
                    # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
                    average_sales = recession_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()        
                    R_chart2  = dcc.Graph(figure = px.bar(average_sales,
                                                          x='Vehicle_Type',
                                                          y='Automobile_Sales',
                                                          title="Average Number of Automobile Sales by Vehicle"
                                                          )
                                          )
                    
            # Plot 3 Pie chart for total expenditure share by vehicle type during recessions
                    # use groupby to create relevant data for plotting
                    exp_rec = recession_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index()
                    R_chart3 = dcc.Graph(figure = px.pie(exp_rec,
                                                         values='Advertising_Expenditure',
                                                         names='Vehicle_Type',
                                                         title="Pie chart for total expenditure share by vehicle type during recessions"
                                                         )
                                        )

            # Plot 4 bar chart for the effect of unemployment rate on vehicle type and sales
                    unemploy_sales = recession_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')[['unemployment_rate','Automobile_Sales']].sum().reset_index()
                    R_chart4 = dcc.Graph(figure = px.bar(unemploy_sales,
                                                         x='unemployment_rate',
                                                         y='Automobile_Sales',
                                                         color = 'Vehicle_Type'                                           
                                                         )
                                        )

            #         return [
            #                 html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart1),html.Div(children=R_chart3)]),
            #                 html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=R_chart2),html.Div(children=R_chart4)])
            #                ]

                    return [
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=R_chart1),
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=R_chart2),
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=R_chart3),
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=R_chart4)
                            ]

            # TASK 2.6: Create and display graphs for Yearly Report Statistics
            # Yearly Statistic Report Plots                             
                elif (input_year and report_type == 'Yearly Statistics'):

                    yearly_data = data[data['Year'] == int(input_year)]

            # Plot 1 Yearly Automobile sales using line chart for the whole period.
                    yas = data.groupby('Year')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
                    Y_chart1 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(yas,
                                                        x='Year',
                                                        y='Automobile_Sales',
                                                        title='Yearly Average Automobile sales'
                                                        )
                                        )

            # Plot 2 Total Monthly Automobile sales using line chart.
                    mas = data.groupby('Month')['Automobile_Sales'].sum().reset_index()    
                    Y_chart2 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.line(mas,
                                                        x='Month',
                                                        y='Automobile_Sales',
                                                        title='Monthly Average Automobile sales'
                                                        )
                                         )

            # Plot bar chart for average number of vehicles sold during the given year
                    avr_vdata = yearly_data.groupby('Month')['Automobile_Sales'].mean().reset_index()
                    Y_chart3 = dcc.Graph(figure=px.bar(avr_vdata,
                                                       x='Month',
                                                       y='Automobile_Sales',
                                                       title='Average Vehicles Sold by Vehicle Type in the year {}'.format(input_year)
                                                       )
                                        )

            # Plot Total Advertisement Expenditure for each vehicle using pie chart
                    exp_data = yearly_data.groupby('Vehicle_Type')['Advertising_Expenditure'].sum().reset_index()
                    Y_chart4 = dcc.Graph(figure = px.pie(exp_data,
                                                         values='Advertising_Expenditure',
                                                         names='Vehicle_Type',
                                                         title="Pie chart for total expenditure by vehicle type "
                                                         )
                                        )

            #TASK 2.6: Returning the graphs for displaying Yearly data
            #         return [
            #                 html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=Y_chart1),html.Div(children=Y_chart3)]),
            #                 html.Div(className='chart-item', children=[html.Div(children=Y_chart2),html.Div(children=Y_chart4)])
            #                ]

                    return [
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=Y_chart1),
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=Y_chart2),
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=Y_chart3),
                            html.Div(className='chart-item', children=Y_chart4)
                           ]

                else:
                    return html.Div('Select a report type and year to view statistics.')

            # Run the Dash app
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I've tried debugging by printing each part of the code but it doesn't seem to be a explicit error, just the graphic functions don't seem to being called correctly.

Comment: What does the code display? (screenshot?) What should it look like?